# Make functioning javascript currency converter

Tags: javascript, html, currency, converters

Im having trouble with the following code.
Here is the html part

```
     <form name="convert">

Choose which currency you would like to convert the Euro to:
<select id="conversionType">
    <option value="polish">Polish Zloty</option>
    <option value="ukraine">Ukraine Hryvnia</option>
</select>
</br>
</br>

<hr>
      Amount:<input id="amount" type="text" />
<input id="convertButton" type="button" value="Convert->"/>
      To:
<input id="answer" type="text" name="answer" readonly="readonly"/>


</form>
```

and here is the javascript code. 
it has been changed and helped before but i cannot see why it is not working

```
    window.onload = initPage;

var euro;
var convert;

function initPage()
{
    document.getElementById("convertButton").onclick = calcAnswer;
    document.getElementById("conversionType").onchange = calcAnswer;
}

function calcAnswer()
{
    //alert(document.getElementById("conversionType").value);

    var value1 = document.getElementById("amount").value1;
    var conversionType = document.getElementById("conversionType").value1;
    //alert(conversionType);

    //if(var value = document.getElementById("conversionType").value=="polish");
    //  document.getElementById("answer").value=value1 * 4.4976;
    //else
    //  document.getElementById("answer").value=value1* 10.43958;


    if(conversionType == "polish") {
        document.getElementById("answer").value1=value1 * 4.4976;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("answer").value1=value1 * 10.43958;
    }


}
```

it will not work at all. i dont know why because i think that the theory is sound. any help wpuld be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Any time you do this:

```
document.getElementById("amount").value1
```

should be this:

```
document.getElementById("amount").value
```

no such thing as value1.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this

```
<pre> document.getElementById("answer").value1 </pre>
```

be

```
 document.getElementById("answer").value = value1 * 4.4976
```